# Should I do git fetch before pull if branch exists locally?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-fetch

I have following question about git.

I novice with git. I want to get last state of `branch1` locally.

now I switched on `branch2` and `branch1` exists locally.

Now I make

1. fetch
2. switch to branch1
3. pull

Please clarify me whether does first `fetch` redundant or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is redundant. Quoting [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> More precisely, `git pull` runs `git fetch` with the given parameters and
>   calls `git merge` to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current
>   branch.

Comment: **git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters**  - what does it mean? I usually just click pull in IDE

Comment: `git pull` is a convenient command for most use cases. It is equal to do a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. `git fetch` updates the rempte branches, e.g. `refs/remotes/origin/branch1`. `git merge` merges the changes of the remote with the local branch.

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can specify several options when `git pull`-ing - some of them are related to merging, some - to fetching. For example, there's a specific set of options when working with so called shallow repositories. But there's a plenty written about it in the very docs I've given link to.